# creating a function to find a certain type of currency and transform it in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been scraching my head with this issue for a while.. i'm a beginner both in python and pandas and i do not know if this is the best way to solve this issue.

I  have a DF with the structure below

[image]

The values for currency can be USD , ARS or NaN.

I'm trying to write a function to transform those ARS value to USD with a set exchange value as it's an approximation.

So far i have wrote something like this .

```
def changeValue(df_price):
    if df_price["currency"] == "ARS" :
        for i in df_price["price"]:
            df_price["price"][i]= df_price["price"][i]/200
    return df_price
```

For some reason i'm getting this error.

KeyError: 'currency'

Edit. I forgot to add that df_price is the entire dataset, also, i'm creating this function to use apply over the dataframe, as in the next line of code.

```
 training_converted = training_data.apply(changeValue,axis= 0)
```

What is my function lacking in order to work with the dataframe . Also, maybe there is a better way of solving this issue using the built in pandas' methods and i'm not aware of it .

Thanks

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please construct a [example], like `df_price = pd.DataFrame(...); changeValue(df_price)` or similar, so we can reproduce your problem easily.

Comment: Is  `df_price` your entire DataFrame, or is `df_price` a subset?  For example, are you passing `changevalue` to `apply`?  That takes different strategies.  Please show us the code that uses this.

Comment: hi @TimRoberts df_price would be the entire dataframe and yes i'm passing changevalue to apply .  This is the line where i was passing it training_converted = training_data.apply(changeValue,axis= 0)

Comment: Then `df_price` is absoluely NOT the entire DataFrame.  It is a subset.  It is being passed one column at a time.  Firstly, you want `axis=1` so it gets called one ROW at a time.  Then, skip the `for` loop.  You're only getting one price per row.  Just return the converted price for whatever this row's currency is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you work with `apply`.  The function gets one row at a time, and you return a value for that row.

```
def changeValue(row):
    if row["currency"] == "ARS" :
        return row["price"]/200
    else
        return row['price']

...

training_converted = training_data.apply(changeValue,axis = 1)
```